# How to chain dropdowns with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

Sorry for the bad title, I don't really know how to formulate it better, would be nice if someone would edit it to make it better fit my idea.

What I'd like to do is click on a company -> that would load all of the given companies departments and when I would click on a department, that would show all of the positions in it.

**Template:**

```
            <label>
                <span style="float: left; width: 100px;">Company</span>
                <select multiple style="width: 670px; float: left; height: 150px;">
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">-----------------------</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="employee in employees | unique: 'company'" ng-bind="employee.company.name"></option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>
                <span style="float: left; width: 100px;">Department</span>
                <select multiple style="width: 670px; float: left; height: 150px;">
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">-----------------------</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="employee in employees | unique: 'department'" ng-bind="employee.department.name"></option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label>
                <span style="float: left; width: 100px;">Position</span>
                <select multiple style="width: 670px; float: left; height: 150px;">
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">-----------------------</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="employee in employees | unique: 'position'" ng-bind="employee.position.name"></option>
                </select>
            </label>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.employees = ContactsApi.Employee.query().$promise.then(function(response) {
    return response;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create three properties on the current scope for the current values of the drop down lists (like currentCompany, currentDepartment and currentEmployee), bind them to the select tags and create watches for each. Then, in the callback function set using $watch, you can load the values for the next drop down list (you might also want to cache the values locally). Please see [this section](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch) for more information
(sorry for the brief answer, I will try to add more details a bit later).

Comment: A bit more details would be nice, yeah :)